# JavaScript function to create 2 soccer teams as even as possible, from a list of players

Tags: javascript, algorithm

? Given a list of players with their respective scores (how well does a player play soccer, from 1 to 5 points), return two teams that are as even as possible.

I've created this code, which is a first version, but I really would like to hear about ideas of how can I improve it.

```
exports.TeamCreator = (function () {

    this.players = [];

    function setPlayers(players){
        this.players = Object.assign([], players);
    }

    function createTeams() {

        var input = this.players;

        var teams = [],
            i = 0,
            scores = [],
            max = input.length;

        scores["A"]=0; scores["B"]=0;
        teams["A"]=[]; teams["B"]=[];

        input.sort(function(a, b){ return b.score - a.score;});

        var nextPlayer;
        var teamForNextPlayer;

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++){

            next();
            teams[teamForNextPlayer].push(nextPlayer);
            scores[teamForNextPlayer] += nextPlayer.score;
        }

        function getBest() {
            nextPlayer = input.splice(0, 1)[0]; //Best in list
        }
        function getWorst() {
            nextPlayer =  input.splice(input.length - 1, 1)[0]; //Worst in list
        }
        function next(){
            var counterA = teams["A"],
                counterB = teams["B"],
                scoreA = scores["A"],
                scoreB = scores["B"];

            if(counterA > counterB) { //B has less players than A
                teamForNextPlayer = "B";

                if(scoreB >= scoreA){
                    getWorst();
                }else{
                    getBest();
                }
            }
            else if(counterA < counterB) { //A has less players than B
                teamForNextPlayer = "A";
                if(scoreA >= scoreB){
                    getWorst();
                }else{
                    getBest();
                }
            }
            else //Same amount of players
            {
                getBest();
                teamForNextPlayer = (scoreA >= scoreB) ? "B" : "A";
            }
        }

        return {
            teamA: teams["A"],
            teamB: teams["B"],
            diff: Math.abs(scores["A"] - scores["B"]),
            scoreA: scores["A"],
            scoreB: scores["B"]
        };

    }
    return {
        setPlayers : setPlayers,
        createTeams: createTeams
    }
}());
```

If it's easier, you can pull the code from [here](https://github.com/klewgenius/match-organizer).

Answer (score 2):

First I would make each team an object with a score and players rather than an object for scores and one for players:

```
var teams = [ { name:'A'; score: 0, players:[] },
              { name:'B', score: 0, players:[] };
```

Once you have sorted the players by score it might be simpler to pick them off the list two at a time and assign the one with the higher score to the lower scoring team:

```
// Note: slice is probably better than Object.assign 
let input = this.players.slice();
assert(input.length % 2 == 0, 'Need an equal number of players');

while (input.length > 0) {
  let [strongerTeam,   weakerTeam]   = teams;
  let [strongerPlayer, weakerPlayer] = input.slice(0,2);
  addPlayer(strongerTeam, weakerPlayer);
  addPlayer(weakerTeam,   strongerPlayer);
  sortTeams(teams); 
}

function addPlayer(team, player) {
  team.players.push(player);
  team.score += player.score;
}

// Sort highest scoring team first
function sortTeams(teams) {
  teams.sort(function(a, b) { return b.score - a.score;});      
}

return teams;
```

One advantage is this always returns the more powerful team first.

---

This algorithm is not ideal in that it doesn't always choose the most balanced team, for example given players with scores of 8, 4, 3, 3, 1 and 1, Team A will have players 8, 3 and 1 (score of 12) while team b will have players with scores of 4, 3 and 1 (totaling 8). It might be more reasonable to balance them as Team A: 8, 1, 1 and Team B 4, 3, 3 so that both teams have a score of 10. The logic for that might be:

```
while (input.length > 0) {
  let [strongerTeam,   weakerTeam]   = teams;
  let nextPlayer = input.slice(0,1)[0];
  addPlayer(weakerTeam,   nextPlayer);
  if (strongerTeam.length - weakerTeam.length == input.length) {
    addPlayers(strongerTeam, input);
    input = [];
  }

  sortTeams(teams); 
}

function addPlayers(team, players) {
  for (let player of players) {
    addPlayer(team, player);
  }
}
```